# WPF MVVM: Binding to a list that is not owned by ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a simple video file manager. Here's the basic functionality:

- The list of video files is read from xml file
- The metadata for video files may be written to the same xml file
- Files are displayed in a DataGrid and metadata may be modified via the DataGrid
- Videos can be launched from the list using an external player (not in the scope of this question)

I have implemented a video library manager, which contains the list of video files and handles serializing and deserializing xml files. Video manager is given to MainViewModel via DI.

```
public class VideoLibraryManager
{
    private VideoLibrary _videoLibrary;

    public void AddVideoFile(VideoFile file) {...}

    public List<VideoFile> GetAllVideos() {...}

    public void SaveToFile(string path) {...}

    public void LoadFromFile(string path) {...}
}

// This class only exists for cleaner xml serialization structure
public class VideoLibrary
{
    public ObservableCollection<VideoFile> Files;
}

public class VideoFile : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _filePath = "";
    public string FilePath
    { 
        get => _filePath;
        set
        {
            _filePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FilePath");
        }
    }

    private string _genre = "";
    public string Genre
    {
        get => _genre;
        set
        {
            _genre = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Genre");
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I bind my DataGrid to a list of video files, which is owned by VideoLibraryManager? Can I bind to it directly? Or do I have to keep a copy of the list in MainViewModel and update it when the original list changes? VideoFile properties should be editable from DataGrid, so binding must be two-way.

Comment: VideoLibraryManager could have a property instead of a GetAllVideos method. The view model could expose the VideoLibraryManager as property. Then you could bind like `ItemsSource="{Binding VideoLibraryManager.AllVideos}"`. Such a Binding does not to be TwoWay in order to support editing. The source property value does not change when element are added to the collection or when elements are modified.

Comment: I would get the data out videolibrarymanager into an observablecollection in MainViewModel , the user edits. Validate. The user commits and the data goes back from mainviewmodel to videolibrarymanager. Here videolibrarymanager is the model in mvvm terms. I would advise against "wrapping" model properties or methods in your viewmodel.

Comment: I would also advise against editing directly in a datagrid unless this is quite simple data.  The pattern I recommend is make datagrids read only. The user selects an item which is copied ( automapper ), They edit the copy in a separate panel. You can then validate and you're not stuck with broken data.  The user can abort and you bin the copy or commit and you replace your original object with the new version.